# Remote mysql database server access denied

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I already have php developed web application on hostinger. i wants to use their database with java application. i used their remote database tutorials. and i used this code to access the database but messege given "access denied". but i connected it with navicat premium through ssh tunnel. tell me the suggestion to access the remote database??

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.xpos.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author Jamith
 */
public class DbConnect {
    static Connection con;
    
    
    private static final String dbHost = "########";
    private static final String port = "####";
    private static final String dbName = "########";
    private static final String userName = "########";
    private static final String password = "########";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        connect();
    }
    
    public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+port+"/"+dbName,userName,password); 
    }
    
    public static void pushToDB(String sql)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
        if(con == null){
            connect();
        }
        con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    
    public static ResultSet getFromDB(String sql)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
        if(con == null){
            connect();
        }
        return con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    }
    
    public static Connection getDBConnection()throws Exception{
        if (con == null) {
            connect();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a proxy configuration missing?

Comment: *i used their remote database tutorials.* Which ones? Normally with hosting services, remote access is disallowed